How do I add environment variables to path in python?
I made a python script to install FFmpeg and add it to path in Windows, but it seemed to have no effect at all. It doesn't give me any errors or anything. It literally just does nothing at all.
This was the code I used:
os.environ["Path"] += f"{os.getcwd()}/ffmpeg-7.0-essentials_build/bin"
os.environ.update()

and I tried several iterations of "path" including "PATH", "Path", "path" and none of them made a difference.
I also tried making a new variable:
new_environ = os.environ["Path"] + f"{os.getcwd()}/ffmpeg-7.0-essentials_build/bin"
os.environ["Path"] = new_environ
os.environ.update()

Which again made no difference.
I know there are other questions like that, but to be honest none of the ones I saw were helpful.

I just tried that code and it works correctly. But the change will only be available inside the Python code. If you want a permanent change then you need to do it either at the command pronpt (just for the current session), or at the System controls.

AFAIK, you need to run the shell command via subprocess to make a permanent change to the OS environment. FYI, in my ffmpeg-downloader package, I have this function [link]:
def set_env_path(dir):
    user_path = get_env("Path")
    if dir not in user_path:
        sp.run(["setx", "Path", user_path + os.pathsep + dir], stdout=sp.DEVNULL)


I did a bit of research and found that I need to use the setx command to make the changes permanent
by adding subprocess.Popen(f"setx Path \"{new_env}\"", shell=True).wait() to the code it seems to have worked fine.

SETX doesn't work because it makes anything "permanent". It changes the global environment, as documented in SETX /?  and may impact other applications running on your system. If that's what you want, it's fine.
